# How to burn hex code program file into AT89S52?

Tags: microcontroller, software, 8051

I am a beginner in Embedded. I have 8051 microcontroller development board with [AT89S52](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc1919.pdf) microcontroller. The board has max232 for serial communication.  I have connected this development board with my laptop using [USB to SERIAL Converter](http://www.amazon.in/dp/B01DHT3CS2/ref=pe_1909141_77686051_tnp_emaildp_1) written C program in [Keil uvision 4](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbjJyN7_jRAhUSSI8KHWDXBzsQFggZMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.keil.com%2Fuvision%2F&usg=AFQjCNESGJ38whFF4Kuj6CztVOQvUKM6wg&sig2=m7t3De29UIVJhBlmP_LGSg&bvm=bv.146094739,d.c2I) and created a hex file. I want to dump this hex file into AT89S52. For that  I am using [FLASH MAGIC tool](http://www.flashmagictool.com/download.html).

But the problem is that  AT89S52 micro controller  is not in FLASH Magic's device database. So what should I do now? Can anybody please tell me is there any other software which supports the at89s52 and windows 7 with usb to rs232 cable?

[image]

Comment: _Which_ dev board do you have? Did it come with any programming documentation and/or software?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I have purchased [this development board](https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://m.ebay.in/itm/8051-Development-Board-with-MAX232-AT89S52-Microcontroller-High-Quality-/301933271789%3Fhash%3DMQ%3D%3D&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=404&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1486390567&sig=AJsQQ1A2lDQcEnXilKZIYmap4Vt48fR7-Q)      with less information about programming of the board

Comment: Does your board has a programming header or is it programmed through the serial port?

Comment: Ok! I just saw the product page. The seller doesn't seem to have provided much info about the product. I would suggest you give him a call. He may be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the AT89S52 has a bootloader burned into it (unlikely) you will *not* be able to program it through the serial port.

Your board has an ISP header on it which is used to program the MCU. You need an interface cable and application designed to program Atmel MCUs via ISP, eg. [Ponyprog](http://www.lancos.com/prog.html).

If your computer has a parallel printer port then you can use the simple circuit found [here](http://elm-chan.org/works/avrx/report_e.html):-

[image]

If you only have USB then get a [USBASP](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) and use [AVRdude](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) as described [here](http://ernstc.dk/arduino/at89s.html) or ProgISP as described [here](https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/8051-tutorials-loading-hex-file-using-progisp/).

Comment: Interesting, although this part is most definitely not an AVR, the implication seems to be that Atmel implemented an ISP process with enough overall similarity to that of their AVRs that some primarily AVR tools have been extended to handle it.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott I have a [laptop](https://www.google.co.in/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwiTz5-5vv7RAhUIH2gKHQNHCZcYABAI&sig=AOD64_1g9AfHm1ZOllMkuXMIzkq2HZaq-w&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwj4m525vv7RAhWKqY8KHbV8BN8QvhcIJw&adurl=) with only USB port but no serial port. Then is there any way to dump code through USB port?

Comment: You need an interface that coverts USB to AVR ISP. USBASP is one http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-USBASP-USBISP-LC-01-51-AVR-Programmer-Adapter-10-Pin-Cable-USB-ATMEGA8-AS-/291938838504?hash=item43f8e927e8:g:Z-4AAOSw4GVYJDx1